# What is our stance on chess riddles?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

This [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5295/brainteaser-what-is-the-one-thing-a-queen-cannot-do-that-all-other-pieces-can-d) is a chess riddle that seems to have been fairly well recieved, although there is doubt about it being on-topic in the comments. But I haven’t seen anything like it since then.

I have an idea in mind for another chess riddle, but I’m not entirely sure if it would be on topic.

Here’s an example. Say I post a riddle that goes as follows: “A knight can’t fork a king and a ____?” The idea for this riddle is to fill in the blank with the answer, which is “Knight.”

To what extent are chess riddles allowed, and what are our confines for what can and can’t be posted as a riddle?

While question askers generally don’t know the answer, and in this case they would, I feel that the CSE communty could have a little fun with chess riddles if it is carefully mannaged (as not to not open unwanted floodagate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**“A knight can’t fork a king and a ____?” The idea for this riddle is to fill in the blank with the answer, which is “Knight.”**

And that answer, of course, is wrong as this example demonstrates NxN is forced for black (although "resigns" would be a better "move") whereupon white retakes and then queens the pawn.

**Knight forking king and knight**

[image]

In general I'm against riddles like this, not least because as this example demonstrates they can often be contentious.